# Using Ember Data's One to Many or Many to Many, how do you specify the relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to using ember data and I'm not clear on exactly how the relationships actually link up to the correct records:

for example let's say I have a transaction and recipient model. The relationship is one to many transactions to recipient. So I as I understand I would have something similar to:

models/transaction.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  recipient: DS.belongsTo('recipient'),
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  amount: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: '1',
      date: '2014/10/06',
      recipient: ??
    }
  ]
});
```

models/recipient.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  transactions: DS.hasMany('transaction')
}).reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Kurt',
      transactions: ??
    }
  ]
});
```

So my question is how do you declare which transaction records belongs to which specific recipient record?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this has already been answered but I cannot find the question to reference it here but I had to fight with this for a while too.

Basically, if you declare one of the properties on your model with `DS.hasMany()` the model will be expecting and array of ID's while if you use `DS.belongsTo()` the model will expect you to provide just the associated ID.

EDIT: Ember-data is expecting your data to pretty much follow what is described here: http://jsonapi.org/

So in your example you should go like this:

```
// models/transaction.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  recipient: DS.belongsTo('recipient', {async:true}),
  date: DS.attr('date'),
  amount: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: '1',
      date: '2014/10/06',
      recipient: 1
    }
  ]
});


//models/recipient.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  transactions: DS.hasMany('transaction', {async:true})
}).reopenClass({
  FIXTURES: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Kurt',
      transactions: [1]
    }
  ]
});
```

Please note that I added the `{async:true}` options hash to the relationship declarations, this will enable your routes to fetch the contents of the relationship asyncronously before presenting the model to the controller (see: http://emberjs.com/api/data/#method_hasMany).

Comment: Thanks much for the help here. However borrowing from your example I am still unable to get the records to match up. I'm going to put together a jsbin and update the question. Wish there were a working example out there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample jsbin showing a working implementation of ember data relational mapping in action:

http://jsbin.com/jihota/3/edit?html,js,output

One of the issues I was having was not understanding that in the template I needed to reference joined table data via 'syntax' so for example a transaction row of data that joins a recipient based on recipient id you would use something like `{{recipient.name}}` instead of just `{{name}}` in the handlebars file to output that joined column.